# Carousel not working for bootstrap v4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a web project and facing problem with carousel, its not moving to next image by clicking or even automatically. Following is my code :

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div id="carousel-testimonial" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel-testimonial" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-testimonial" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-testimonial" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="carousel-item active text-center">
            <img src="images/client-01.jpg" alt="testimonial" class="center-block">
            <div class="testimonial-caption">
                <h2>Danial</h2>
                <h4><span>Sr. Software Engineer, </span>Blue Gyms</h4>
                <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et olore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip."</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item text-center">
            <img src="images/client-02.jpg" alt="testimonial" class="center-block">
            <div class="testimonial-caption">
                <h2>Rauls Pole</h2>
                <h4><span>Marketing Manager, </span>Risco</h4>
                <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et olore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip."</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item text-center">
            <img src="images/client-03.jpg" alt="testimonial" class="center-block">
            <div class="testimonial-caption">
                <h2>Jack</h2>
                <h4><span>Sr. Software Engineer, </span>Blue Gyms</h4>
                <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et olore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip."</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you're using bootstrap 4?

Comment: @MichaelCoker yes

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to include the buttons into your carousel. These are the a-links at the end of the following example. Furthermore, have you included jQuery and the Bootstrap 4 JavsScripts in your project? You find all necessary lines [here](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/introduction/#quick-start).

```
<div id="carousel-testimonial" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel-testimonial" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-testimonial" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-testimonial" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="carousel-item active text-center">
            <img src="images/client-01.jpg" alt="testimonial" class="center-block">
            <div class="testimonial-caption">
                <h2>Danial</h2>
                <h4><span>Sr. Software Engineer, </span>Blue Gyms</h4>
                <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore
                    et olore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
                    aliquip."</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item text-center">
            <img src="images/client-02.jpg" alt="testimonial" class="center-block">
            <div class="testimonial-caption">
                <h2>Rauls Pole</h2>
                <h4><span>Marketing Manager, </span>Risco</h4>
                <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore
                    et olore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
                    aliquip."</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item text-center">
            <img src="images/client-03.jpg" alt="testimonial" class="center-block">
            <div class="testimonial-caption">
                <h2>Jack</h2>
                <h4><span>Sr. Software Engineer, </span>Blue Gyms</h4>
                <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore
                    et olore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
                    aliquip."</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel-testimonial" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel-testimonial" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have already included jquery and bootstrap js also I have tried   including button but still not working and also buttons are optional

Comment: Hard to tell what's not working from here. But here are some points for debugging: Is there something in the console? Does it work in other browsers? How does it work as a single element in a HTML file?